# How to get data stored in local storage into an array to print in html cart?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have stored the items from the cart into the localstorage and it all works fine. in the cart.component.ts i want to print out the products in an array.

At the moment, this....

```
cartItem:number = 0;

cartItemFunc(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('localCart') !=null){
    var cartZ = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localCart')as string);
    this.cartItem = cartZ.length;
    console.log(cartZ);
  }
  }
```

...gives me only the number of how many items are in the local storage saved..but i need an array that stores every item, so that I can add that to the html.
At the beginning i had a manual table:

```
//public cartItems: cartitem[] = [
   // { produktid: 1 , produtName: 'Tshirt Type A',productPrice: 4, qtty: 2 },
    //{ produktid: 2 , productName: 'Figurine A',productPrice: 16, qtty: 1 },
    //{ produktid: 3 , productName: 'Figurine X',productPrice: 62, qtty: 3 },
    //{ produktid: 4 , productName: 'Hoodie',productPrice: 30, qtty: 2 },
    //{ produktid: 5 , productName: 'Tshirt Type B',productPrice: 6, qtty: 1 }
  //];
```

this worked very nicely, but obviously wasnt well done so I have to add Items to the cart now.

I tried this, but obviously it doesnt work:

```
getCart(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('localCart') !=null){
      for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        this.cartItems[i] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localCart')as string);
      }
      console.log(this.cartItems); //to check if there is anything in the Array
    }
  }
```

How do i do it and how do I even get the data of each product? Like the price of each product, since I would need to calculate that together...

Comment: you have to stringify the object after you get it from local storage.  they you can use a forEach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial Declaration

```
cartItems: cartitem[] = [
   { produktid: 1 , produtName: 'Tshirt Type A',productPrice: 4, qtty: 2 },
   { produktid: 2 , productName: 'Figurine A',productPrice: 16, qtty: 1 },
   { produktid: 3 , productName: 'Figurine X',productPrice: 62, qtty: 3 },
   { produktid: 4 , productName: 'Hoodie',productPrice: 30, qtty: 2 },
   { produktid: 5 , productName: 'Tshirt Type B',productPrice: 6, qtty: 1 }
];
cartItem:number = cartItems.lenght;

---
this.setCart(cartItems);
this.cartItems = this.getCart();
this.cartItem =  this.cartItems.lenght;
---
```

// Serialize and STORE the cart in localstore:

```
setCart(cartItems:cartitem[]){
   const carItemsString:string = JSON.stringify(cartItems);
   localStorage.setItem('localCarts', carItemsString);
}
```

// READ the cart from localstorage and Deserialize

```
getCart(): cartitem[]{

   const carts: cartitem[] = [];

   if(localStorage.getItem('localCarts') !=null){
       const carItemsString= localStorage.getItem('localCarts');
       carts = JSON.parse(carItemsString);

       //this.cartItem = cartItems.length;
       //console.log(cartItem);
  }

  return carts;

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i got a problem tho in setItem on stringify : Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
lib.es5.d.ts(1066, 15): An argument for 'value' was not provided.
(method) JSON.stringify(value: any, replacer?: ((this: any, key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined, space?: string | number | undefined): string (+1 overload)

Comment: Sory, my mistake. I edited it, it's: const carItemsString:string = JSON.stringify( cartItems );        More info about stringify: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: I see in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693740/how-to-get-the-numbers-from-a-string-to-calculate-them-together-in-angular-types that you finally used my solution. Could you please mark as good answer if it helped? Thxs.

Comment: thank you for telling me! New to stackoverflow, now i did it. Thank you alot for everything and I wish you only the best!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad it helped you! See you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getCart(){
        const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localCart'));
        if( cart && cart.length){
          for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            this.cartItems[i] = cart;
          }
          console.log(this.cartItems); //to check if there is anything in the Array
        }
      }
```

Comment: thank you! for some reasin it doesnt work tho. I have put this in the onInit to test it out, but it throws errors 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at t.getCart (main.3a95c60344cc72f296f2.js:formatted:15472)
    at t.ngOnInit (main.3a95c60344cc72f296f2.js:formatted:15451)

this.cartItems[i] = cart; 
This is where the error happens...cartItems , what exactly should that be? Array, any type? How do I make it a array to put the Items from the localStorage in D: