# How to get the numbers from a string to calculate them together in angular/typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a longer string: cartString with Strings in it

Console OutPut after console.log(this.cartString);:

```
[{"Name":"A","Price":2.99},{"Name":"B","Price":5.99},{"Name":"C","Price":8.99}]
```

Oh the named String I want to save the numbers somehow to later calculate them together for a Total amount.

The numbers can always be different depending on what is saved in the string so unluckily I cannot just compare it to exactly this..would be to easy.
The:

var isNumber = rxjsNumeric.isNumeric(testString) testing also doesnt want to work for me to first check if a string is numeric, i guess because its just to big...

**What I want to do, is just calculate the price total of those numbers of the given string. I know how to do that, but not how to get them first out of the string! Help please, i would really much appreciate! And I am sorry for all my questions.**

cartstring!: string; is a string that i generated from the localStorage, but i dont think thats important, i just want the Numbers of it D:

Here is how I got the cartString anyway:

```
getCart(){
    let carts:cartitem[] = [];
      if(localStorage.getItem('localCart') !=null){ 
        this.cartSring= localStorage.getItem('localCart')as string;
        carts = JSON.parse(this.cartString);
    }
    return carts;
    }
```

GetCart() Array OUtput:

```
0: {Name: "A", Price: 2.99}
1: {Name: "B", Price: 5.99}
2: {Name: "C", Price: 8.99}
```

Why I dont use the array: Because I dont know how to print it correctly in the HTML. When I try to use it, I get an error...so I converted it to a string.

If there is more information needed, please let me know before - this, since I am still searching for an answer! Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `Price` property and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to calculate the sum:

```js
const obj = [{"Name":"A","Price":"2.99"},{"Name":"B","Price":"5.99"},{"Name":"C","Price":"8.99"}]
const priceSum = obj.map(e => parseFloat(e.Price)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(priceSum);
```

Comment: thank you so much! I appreciate the help alot and it works

Comment: @user16600500 No problem. If it helps, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer :)

Comment: thanks, the only problem is , that on other arrays of this type it wouldnt work D: I tried to clone my Array with the Objects in it, but unluckily it doesnt see the Price or better said it says "Property Price does not exist on type 'never' . Weird, i thought i did copy the array... like this:
const myClonedArray  = Object.assign([], this.getCart());
  const priceSum = myClonedArray.map(e => parseFloat(e.Price)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  console.log(priceSum);

Answer (score -1):

You can use *regex* to check if there are numbers and could get the positions, so that you can extract the strings from those positions and just *parseInt()* it.
Since the console output is an array with objects, its much easier.

Now you can use *ngFor to loop through each items and then you can display each one's name and price by item['Name'] and item['Price'], or item.Name and item.Price

Comment: I have added the console output of the string, is it correct , to put it like this? Thank you very very much

Comment: Since the console output is an array with objects, its much easier.

Now you can use *ngFor to loop through each items and then you can display each one's name and price by item['Name'] and item['Price'], or item.Name and item.Price

Comment: aah so instead of just the {{cartString}} in the HTML i would need to put in the listing that i have <li *ngFor = "let item of getCart()" > ? the {{item.Price}} right? If i did it correctly, then unluckily it doesnt work. When I tried just {{item}} to check the output ,it came out : [object Object]

Comment: getCart() is the method of the lowest function. There I get the Array of the Objects

Comment: This should have worked. Why dont you try storing these data inside a variable and then using ngFor with that variable

Comment: I provided one of the possible answers and I wanted the user with the question to check if it works. I fnot, I could get into it more deeper.

Comment: well the problem is, that i dont quiet know how to store every one of the Objects into a variable. As i Understood the Array is out of Objects so Id need to store every one of those in a variable, correct?